# Aliasing example, try to understand this issue

Tags: c#, pointer-aliasing

I try to learn about `Aliasing` and encounter this example:

```
public class A
{
    // Instance variable 
    private double _x;

    // 3 constructors 

    public A(double x)
    {
        _x = x;
    }

    public A()
    {
        _x = 0;
    }

    public A(A a)
    {
        _x = a._x;
    }

    // methods 
    public double getX()
    {
        return _x;
    }

    public void setX(double x)
    {
        _x = x;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "A:" + _x;
    } 
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A a1 = new A(7);
    A a2 = new A(a1);
    A a3 = a2;

    Console.WriteLine("a1 = " + a1.toString());
    Console.WriteLine("a2 = " + a2.toString());
    Console.WriteLine("a3 = " + a3.toString());

    a1.setX(10);
    Console.WriteLine("after setting 10 to a1:");
    Console.WriteLine("a1 = " + a1.toString());
    Console.WriteLine("a2 = " + a2.toString());
    Console.WriteLine("a3 = " + a3.toString());

    a3.setX(5);
    Console.WriteLine("after setting 5 to a3:");
    Console.WriteLine("a1 = " + a1.toString());
    Console.WriteLine("a2 = " + a2.toString());
    Console.WriteLine("a3 = " + a3.toString());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The first `Console.WriteLine` and the first `SetX` is clrea but why after `a3.setX(5)`, also a2 changed ?
According the declaration `A a3 = a2` and SetX refer to `a3`

Answer (score 2):

Both `a2` and `a3` are references¹ to the same object. Since you have **one** object (and **two** references to it), changing the object by means of any reference will produce changes visible, again, by means of any reference.

---

¹ *Reference* here is Java jargon for what in C/C++ is called *pointer*. And your example will show the same behaviour when you have pointer aliasing in those languages.

Comment: Technically there no pointers here. Consider changing the word "pointer" to "reference".

Comment: and why after set a1 to 10, a2 is still remained 7 ?

Comment: Because `a1` is a reference to one object, and both `a2` and `a3` are references to *another* object. In total, you create two objects and three references, with `a2` and `a3` aliasing each other. What happens to the object referenced by `a1` is of course not visible through `a2` nor `a3`.